# I had g++, was using it, installed make, and now g++ is impossible to install

Tags: debian, g++

I am running Debian 8.1. I installed g++ via the terminal using apt-get. I then installed build-essential, and saw something in the terminal about "removing g++". I freaked out a little, because I've spent the better part of two days getting Debian to actually install on this computer. I tried to use g++ again, and it was just gone. I removed what I had just downloaded, tried to install g++ again and now I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
g++ : Depends: g++-4.4 (>= 4.4.5-1~) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: gcc-4.4 (>= 4.4.5-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know what to do and I'm frustrated enough right now that I feel like my head is going to pop.

The output of `apt-cache policy g++ g++-4.4 gcc-4.4` is

```
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.4.5-1
  Version table:
     4:4.4.5-1 0
        500 ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze/main amd64 Packages
g++-4.4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.5-8
  Version table:
     4.4.5-8 0
        500 ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze/main amd64 Packages
gcc-4.4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.5-8
  Version table:
     4.4.5-8 0
        500 ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: For some reason you're tracking Squeeze (Debian 6.0); how did you install Debian?

Comment: I installed Debian with the amd64 iso image on a DVD-r. I'm dual booting it with windows 8.1.

Comment: So did you mean to say that you are running **Windows** 8.1 but **Debian** 6.0?

Comment: No. I am running Debian 8.1 (Jessie).

Comment: I'm probably just going to reboot from the dvd, erase all the data in my partitions, and re-install the whole thing. C++ is the primary language I develop in, so having rendered myself incapable of doing so in this operating system is just a little bit problematic. If I installed it once then by god I'll do it again.

Comment: Before re-installing, try fixing up your sources (see my answer); it might save you some time...

Comment: Oh wow. It works now. I can not thank you enough, you just made my day 200 percent better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you installed Debian 8.1, your package sources should refer to `jessie`, not `squeeze`. You should edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` referring to `squeeze`) and replace `squeeze` with `jessie`.

Once that's done,

```
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get install build-essential
```

should restore `g++` (`build-essential` depends on `g++` and `make`).